# Opencv, Xcode : '_MM_SHUFFLE2' macro redefined, multiple semantic errors when building opencv

Tags: opencv

I'm currently trying to build an opencv project, but I keep getting redefined errors  http://pastebin.com/v1RgnNS0 originating from the core.hpp included.

The code was working yesterday, but having changed some of the settings for the project and I'm unsure what needs to be changed to fix this problem. Does anyone have any experience with fixing this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by removing references to existing frameworks that were added, and then reading just the ones required - paying particular attention to use the same .dylibs for opencv for both main and test.